# jQuery: JSON value not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, json

I'm building a 'Name That Tune' web app using the iTunes API. I submit a search request to iTunes and get back a JSON object. I then store the previewURL (the song snippet) and trackName (song name). I use the trackName to check if the user submitted the correct guess and I use it to display the song name on the UI when the guess is wrong so user knows what the correct answer was.

Issues: 
1. When displaying the song name on the UI it displays as [object object]. However, it displays on the console correctly - i.e. it shows the song name. In my example, the song is 'backroads'. 
2. The function that checks if the guess was correct is not working. Every guess, even the correct ones, are shown as incorrect..which I guess I would expect given issue #1.

See attachment.[image]

Things I tried:
1. Searching for other similiar issues but didn't find anything that was right.
2. Used a toSTring on the variable. Same bad results.
3. Passed the songName into the 2nd function as a parameter.

Below is JS code in question.

```
// when user clicks Play get song preview from iTunes and play, show songguess and hide genresection
$("button#playSong").click(function(){

    $('.genreSection').hide();  
    $('#guessFields').show();

    // get genre user selected
    var genreSelected = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    console.log("Genre selected is: "+genreSelected);

    // get song for genre selected     
    $.post("https://itunes.apple.com/search?kind=song&limit=1&term="+genreSelected,                  

    // Get song preview url and define to audio source 'src' to play the song preview
    function(data){
        console.log(data);

        // get song name
        var songName = data.results[0].trackName;
        console.log("Song name is: "+songName);

        $("#songAudio").attr("src",data.results[0].previewUrl);
        $("#audioCtrl")[0].load();
        $("#audioCtrl")[0].play();
        },
    'json');  // identifies the format of the data returned
});

// when user submits guess
$("button#guessSong").click(function(songName){

        // get countdown seconds remaining

        // if countdown is less than 1, hid submit button and display message "too late"

        // get value of song guess
        var songGuess = $("#songGuess").val();
        console.log("Song guess is: "+songGuess);

    // hide input field and button
        $('#guessFields').hide();   

        // check if guess is correct
        if(songGuess === songName) {

            // increment correct guess counter
            correctGuessCounter++;
            console.log("Correct guess counter is "+correctGuessCounter);

            // display you are correct message
            $("#results").html("Correct! Your points for that guess are "+correctGuessCounter);

        }else {

            //convert songname to string
            songName = songName.toString();

            // display you are correct message
            $("#results").html("Sorry, wrong answer. The correct song name is "+songName+".");
        }
```

Comment: The first parameter inside a click callback function is the event data, which is an object and not the "songName" that you are expecting, which also lead to your next issue where your are comparing between a string and an object.

Comment: Ok I get that. Thanks. Could you suggest how I can resolve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`songName` in your second click function is a parameter to the function. Since it's a click event, the value of `songName` will be an event object, not a song name.

I'm not sure how you intend to store the song name, but you might want to store it in a variable or something, outside the scope of the click functions so that both of them can see it.

Declare `songName` up above both functions:

```
var songName;

// when user clicks Play get song preview from iTunes and play, show 
// songguess and hide genresection
$("button#playSong").click(function(){
```

Make sure to remove `var` from `songName` on the assignment line, or else it will hide the `songName` from above.

```
   // Get song preview url and define to audio source 'src' to play the song preview
   function(data){
      console.log(data);

      // get song name
      songName = data.results[0].trackName;
      console.log("Song name is: "+songName);
```

Make sure to remove `songName` from the parameter list, or else it too will hide the outer one.

```
// when user submits guess
$("button#guessSong").click(function(){

   ...

   // check if guess is correct
    if(songGuess === songName) {

      ...
```

Comment: Since the click event is what triggers the API call to iTunes, can you recommend an approach to store the song name variable outside the function?

Comment: @TPop I did, didn't I? Edited to be a little more clear.